# Program crash in wstringstream

Tags: c++

My program is crashing in the `wstringstream` line, I think it's because sometimes it searches for a `msg` that doesn't exist inside of `wmTranslation`, how I could 'fix' this?

```
const char* TranslateMessage(int Msg) {
    static std::map<int, const char*> wmTranslation = {
        {0, "WM_NULL" },
        {1, "WM_CREATE" },
        {2, "WM_DESTROY" },
        //...
    };

    const char* translatedMessage = "Unknown message";

    translatedMessage = wmTranslation[Msg];

    return translatedMessage;
}

    const char* translatedMessage = TranslateMessage(Msg);

    std::wstringstream text;
    text << L"Msg: " << Msg << L" - " << translatedMessage;
    OutputDebugString(text.str().c_str());
```

Comment: Check if `translatedMessage` is a nullptr to avoid this issue. In `translatedMessage = wmTranslation[Msg];` the `translatedMessage` will be set to a null pointer and be added to the map if the Msg is not in the map.

Comment: `translatedMessage = wmTranslation[Msg];` -- A mistake made by many.  This adds an entry to the map if `Msg` is not found.  I bet you weren't aware this was going on behind-your-back.

Comment: You may be at a _design stage_ at this point.  What do you want to promise that `TranslateMessage` will do, when given an invalid `msg`?  Throw an exception?  Return null?  Return some dummy "INVALID" string?

Comment: Related to my first comment: [https://ideone.com/aFRwXg](https://ideone.com/aFRwXg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking up a key that doesn't exist adds an entry for the key, with a default value (the null pointer in your case).

Check if the key exists first, then return the relevant value.

```
const char* TranslateMessage(int Msg) {
    static std::map<int, const char*> wmTranslation = {
        {0, "WM_NULL" },
        {1, "WM_CREATE" },
        {2, "WM_DESTROY" },
        //...
    };
    auto it = wmTranslation.find(Msg);
    return it != wmTranslation.end() ? it->second : "Unknown message";
}
```

If all the values are consecutive integers from zero upwards, you might consider using a vector (or an array) rather than a map, and index with `Msg`.

Comment: Thank you, whenever it finds the message it returns immediately or it does run through all values inside of the `map` before returning?

Comment: There is no vector involved here. It uses the map to find. It's not a linear search.

Comment: Yes, my mistake, but I still don't understand what you mean which linear search.

Comment: @Forth *or it does run through all values* -- This implies a linear search, and that is not how a `std::map` works when finding a key.  A `map` is not like a vector with some extra member functions.

Comment: Also, with this solution the map can be made `const`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie so would be 'better' to write it as a vector? I mean it would be 'faster' than using the map?

Comment: [Please see this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find).   For a map with `N` items, the `find()` will make log(N) probes to find an entry.  Which one is "faster" depends on the number of entries and other factors.  But algorithmically, a lookup in a map will be faster.  If the map has maybe less than a few hundred entries, the difference in search probably won't be anything significant compared to vector.  A map with thousands or millions of entries, then we're talking a huge difference.